# Singular points of evolute and pedal

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $\gamma$ be a unit speed plane curve $\gamma : I \to \mathbb R^2$.

$T(s),N(s),k(s)$ are unit tangent vector, unit normal vector, curvature repectively.

Evolute and pedal are defined as:

$EV(s)=\gamma (s)+\frac{1}{k(s)}N(s),k(s) \ne 0,$

$P (s) = (\gamma (s) \cdot N(s)) N(s)$.

I want to find proofs of the following statements:

1. $s_0$ is the singular point of the evolute if and only if $k'(s_0)=0$.
2. $s_0$ is the singular point of the pedal if and only if $k(s_0)=0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$First thing to notice: $\gamma$ having unit speed doesn't mean that ${\rm EV}$ and $\rm P$ also have unit speed. That being said, note that: $${\rm EV}'(s) = \cancel{{\bf T}(s)} - \frac{\kappa'(s)}{\kappa(s)^2}{\bf N}(s) + \cancel{\frac{1}{\kappa(s)}(-\kappa(s){\bf T}(s))} = -\frac{\kappa'(s)}{\kappa(s)^2}{\bf N}(s).$$With this in mind, use the definition: $s_0$ is a singular point of $\rm EV$ if and only if ${\rm EV}'(s_0) = 0$. But since ${\bf N}(s), \kappa(s) \neq 0$ for all $s \in I$ (in particular for $s_0$), by the above expression we have that ${\rm EV}'(s_0) = 0 \iff \kappa'(s_0) = 0$. The exact same approach can be done for $\rm P$, and I think you are capable of doing it, mimicking my work above.

---

Since you actually tried to do it, let's do a complete solution. For the next one, we have that: $$\begin{align} {\rm P}'(s) &= (\gamma'(s)\cdot {\bf N}(s)){\bf N}(s) + (\gamma(s) \cdot {\bf N}'(s)){\bf N}(s) + (\gamma(s)\cdot {\bf N}(s)){\bf N}'(s) \\ &+ \cancelto{0}{({\bf T}(s)\cdot {\bf N}(s)){\bf N}(s)} -\kappa(s) (\gamma(s) \cdot {\bf T}(s)){\bf N}(s) -\kappa(s) (\gamma(s)\cdot {\bf N}(s)){\bf T}(s) \\ &= -\kappa(s) \left((\gamma(s) \cdot {\bf T}(s)){\bf N}(s) + (\gamma(s)\cdot {\bf N}(s)){\bf T}(s)\right)\end{align}$$We have that $\kappa(s_0) = 0 \implies {\rm P}'(s_0) = 0$, clear. Now suppose that ${\rm P}'(s_0) = 0$.

We have two possibilities:

**1)** $\kappa(s_0) = 0$, or;

**2)** $(\gamma(s_0) \cdot {\bf T}(s_0)){\bf N}(s_0) + (\gamma(s_0)\cdot {\bf N}(s_0)){\bf T}(s_0) = 0$.

Let's prove that **2)** can't happen. Since $\{   {\bf T}(s_0),{\bf N}(s_0)\}$ is a orthonormal set, we get $\gamma(s_0) = 0$. In details, **2)** implies that: $$\gamma(s_0)\cdot {\bf T}(s_0) = \gamma(s_0)\cdot {\bf N}(s_0) = 0,$$ and so $$\gamma(s_0) = (\gamma(s_0)\cdot {\bf T}(s_0)){\bf T}(s_0) + (\gamma(s_0)\cdot {\bf N}(s_0)){\bf N}(s_0) = 0\cdot {\bf T}(s_0)+0\cdot {\bf N}(s_0)  = 0.$$ This is the extra hypothesis we need for the implication $\impliedby$ to be true ($\gamma$ not passing through the origin). You can see [here](http://www.emis.de/monographs/CGM/1.html), in item **c)**. This gives the contradiction needed, hence we get $\kappa(s_0) = 0$, as wanted.

Comment: I found $ P' = -kA$ where $A=(\gamma T)N +(\gamma N) T$. To solve $A=0$, using the facts that $NT=0, T^2=1$ gives us $\gamma N=0$. Differentiating both sides we get $-k\gamma'\gamma=0$ i.e. $k(\|\gamma\|^2)'=0$. Since $\|\gamma\|^2$ is constant then this equation is always true?! Does this make any sense?

Comment: You can't differentiate things because we have stopped at $s_0$. Also, $\|\gamma'\|$ is constant, not $\|\gamma\|$. I'll think a bit.

Comment: I think we should prove that $A=0 \iff \gamma=0$. But haven't gotten any clue yet.

Comment: There was a hypothesis missing. I added some things in the answer and a link, please check it.

Comment: "For a general curve $\bf X$, *which does not pass through the origin*...."

Comment: Very kind answer. Thank you @IvoTerek.